# Single-layer Perceptron

Tags: algorithm, perceptron

I'm building a single-layer perceptron that has a reasonably long feature vector (30-200k), all normalised.

Let's say I have 30k features which are somewhat useful at predicting a class but then add 100 more features which are excellent predictors. The accuracy of the predictions only goes up a negligible amount. However, if I manually increase the weights on the 100 excellent features (say by 5x), the accuracy goes up several percent.

It was my impression that the nature of the training process should give better features a higher weight naturally. However, it seems like the best features are being 'drowned out' by the worse ones.

I tried running it with a larger number of iterations, but that didn't help.

How can I adapt the algorithm to better weight features in a reasonably simple way? Also, a reasonably fast way; if I had fewer features it'd be easy to just run the algorithm leaving one out at a time but it's not really feasible with 30k.

Comment: I am not an expert, but for what it's worth: I think it is important to look at the details of (i) the exact training algorithm, (ii) the number of training examples, (iii) the quality of the examples, (iv) questions like the linear separability of the desired class.

Comment: Care to tell us about your training algorithm?

Comment: Find the class that maximizes weight[class] * feature_vector. If it is the correct class, do nothing. If it is incorrect, add feature[i] to all weight[reaL_class][i] and subtract feature[i] from all weight[predicted_class][i]. Repeat x times. Average weights over x when done.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with implementing perceptron based network is that it takes a lot of iterations to learn something. I believe I used each sample about 1k times to learn the xor function(when having only 4 inputs). So if you have 200k inputs it will take a lot of samples and a lot of time to train your network.

I have a few suggestions for you:

- try to reduce the size of the input(try to aggregate several inputs into a single one or try to remove redundant once).
- try to use each sample more times. As I said it may take a lot of iterations to learn even a simple function

Hope this helps.